# How to redirect to another page after 5 minutes?

Tags: php, javascript, html, timer

How do I redirect to another page after 5 minutes using PHP?

Comment: You will need html and/or JavaScript for this, not PHP

Comment: Read a bit about client side (JavaScript) and server side (PHP, Java, ASP, etc) languages and principles before venturing any further. Honest advice.

Comment: You surely read the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Techniques, didn't you? That gives you a short introduction.

Comment: thnx guys really appreciate ur help<br>@eckes ave not read that article but will surely read it,thnx 4 da link ..a

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you really want to use PHP for this, here you go:

```
<?php header("Refresh: 300; URL=http://www.stackoverflow.com/"); ?>
```

Answer (score 12):

With just HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300;http://redirect-url" />
```

This will redirect to `http://redirect-url` after 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Comment: thnx guys really appreciate ur help

Answer (score 5):

Javascript's setTimeout() is probably what you want. An example would be:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "<URL HERE>";}, 5*60*1000);
```

window.location is what you can use in javascript to set the current location of the window. Something to consider, however, is that most browsers do not let you set window.location without some type of user input before hand, such as a click.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: thnx @Will Charczuk but my time is taking less than a minute when i use this one..

Comment: try substituting 5*60*1000 with 300000